# Помогите разобраться с передаваемыми значениями в конструктор класса std::optional (& и &&)

Tags: c++, конструктор, c++17, optional

Что должно передаваться в эти конструкторы класса:

```
    constexpr optional( const optional& other );
    constexpr optional( optional&& other ) noexcept();
```

В чем разница между & и && и зачем мы объявляем аргумент константным?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`optional&& other` - это объявление rvalue-ссылки. Это ссылка на временный объект. Это позволяет компиляторам задействовать move-семантику, когда объекты не копируются, а получают ресурс. Одна из практик - запрет конструктора копирования, оставив только конструктор перемещения - тогда объекты можно только перемещать. Как пример - `unique_ptr`.
Аргумент `optional( const optional& other );` объявляется константным, чтобы компилятор мог защитить программиста от ошибки - в теле функции не должно быть операций, изменяющих первоначальный объект, переданный по ссылке.